# What does an 8 indicate in the Select Field of NTP Peer status?

Tags: ntp

I've done `ntpq`, then ran `associations` and received the following:

```
ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 12097  c811   yes  none   yes    reject    mobilize  1
```

From the documentation from `man ntp-decode` (Peer Status), I've learned that the first digit indicates `Status`, the second `Select`, the third `Count`, and the fourth `Code`.

I've tried to find the  `Select Status` section of this manual and found the following:

```
The Select Field displays the current selection status. (The T Field in the following table gives the corresponding tally codes used in the ntpq peers dis-
play.) The values are coded as follows:

+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        Code             |            Message                    |            T             |            Description                                      |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        0                |            sel_reject                 |                          |            discarded as not valid (TEST10-TEST13)           |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1                |            sel_falsetick              |            x             |            discarded by intersection algorithm              |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        2                |            sel_excess                 |            .             |            discarded by table overflow (not used)           |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        3                |            sel_outlyer                |            -             |            discarded by the cluster algorithm               |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        4                |            sel_candidate              |            +             |            included by the combine algorithm                |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        5                |            sel_backup                 |            #             |            backup (more than tos maxclock sources)          |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        6                |            sel_sys.peer               |            *             |            system peer                                      |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        7                |            sel_pps.peer               |            o             |            PPS peer (when the prefer peer is valid)         |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, what does the `8` digit for `Select Status` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [explanation of peer status codes in the docs](http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/decode.html#peer) says that the status field "is 5 bits wide, and combines with the the 3-bit-wide Select Field to create the first full byte of the peer status word."  The select field is 3 bits, so it can only have the values 0-7.  The 8 in the 2nd digit is the least-significant bit in the status field, not the most-significant bit in the select field.

So `c8` means "persistent association", "authentication enabled", and "broadcast association" (bits 0, 1, and 4, counting big-endian).  You can get `ntpq` to interpret these fields for you by using the `readvar` command.  Here's an example from my laptop, which is configured to use `[0-3].ubuntu.pool.ntp.org` in `pool` mode:

```
# ntpq -n
ntpq> peers
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 1.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
...
ntpq> assoc

ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 32962  8811   yes  none  none    reject    mobilize  1
  2 32963  8811   yes  none  none    reject    mobilize  1
...
ntpq> readvar 32962
associd=32962 status=8811 conf, bcast, sel_reject, 1 event, mobilize,
srcadr=0.0.0.0, srcport=0, srchost="0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org",
dstadr=0.0.0.0, dstport=0, leap=11, stratum=16, precision=-24,
rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=0.000, refid=POOL,
reftime=00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036 16:28:16.000,
...
```

Note the "conf" (permanently-configured association) and "bcast" (broadcast association), which are short interpretations of the status field.  (Apparently broadcast can mean more than just broadcast when it has a refid of POOL.)